# django-filter - show only relevant filter values

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I am using django-filters and can't figure out how to display only relevant to my queryset filter values.

From code below I am displaying products by specific category but I receive all filter values that might not be applicable to that category. How do I display only relevant filter values?

models.py

```
Class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512, unique=True, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=512, unique=True, db_index=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    common_attributes = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

Class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    manufacturer = django_filters.AllValuesMultipleFilter(name='manufacturer', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

Class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['manufacturer']
```

views.py

```
def show_category(request, category_slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    subcategories = Category.objects.filter(parent_id=category.id)
    products = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.filter(categories=category).annotate(starting_price=Min('variant__price')))
    breadcrumbs = Category.get_parents(category.id)
    return render(request, 'catalog/category.html', {'category' : category, 'subcategories' : subcategories, 'breadcrumbs' : breadcrumbs, 'products' : products})
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what information you are wanting to get?  We don't have any way of knowing what information is and isn't applicable to your category, since we aren't writing your code.

Comment: I have a list of products which belong to different categories and the view above renders products which belong to a single category. I would like to implement a simple filter as seen on any modern eCommerce website so users can filter by brand, price, rating, etc. The code above partially works, it filters by manufacturer as expected but it displays all manufacturers even the one that are not applicable to that category.

Comment: Let's say you have Book1 of category Books and Manufacturer A and you have magazine2 of category Magazines and Manufacturer B. When looking at Books category, filter will display both options - Manufacturer A and B. I want it to only display Manufacturer A.